# What does the exponential of a vector do geometrically?

Tags: geometry, vectors, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

The exponential of an even multi-vector is related to rotation, but what is the exponential of a vector?

For instance, the exponential of a vector $\mathbf{v}=x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+z\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ is:

$$
\exp (x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+z\hat{\mathbf{z}} )=\cosh (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+z^2})+\frac{x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+y\hat{\mathbf{y}}+z\hat{\mathbf{z}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\sinh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})
$$

What does it do geometrically?

Comment: The geometry is basically the same whether the dot product is positive-definite or negative-definite. But if $\mathbf v^2=-\lVert\mathbf v\rVert^2<0$, then the exponential is $$\exp(\mathbf v)=\cos\lVert\mathbf v\rVert+\frac{\mathbf v}{\lVert\mathbf v\rVert}\sin\lVert\mathbf v\rVert,$$ and circular functions are not basically the same as hyperbolic functions. ($\sin$ is bounded and periodic; $\sinh$ is unbounded and monotonic.) So I don't expect it to have any "geometric significance", whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the exponential of an odd-grade multivector can be interpreted as a [hyperbolic rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping). The combination of regular (spherical) rotations and hyperbolic rotations gives you the [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation), which are fundamental to relativistic physics.